# JSON RPC with digest auth

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, rpc

Is there anyone using Monero JSON RPC authentication?
I can only use curl with username:password to request the daemon RPC. But I cannot do the request with nodejs.
Anyone tried with nodejs successfully with digest auth?

Answer (score 2):

I've got a working JSON RPC wrapper with digest auth working in https://github.com/sneurlax/moneronodejs (merging into https://github.com/monero-integrations/moneronodejs, I hope.)  Here's the relevant code:

lib/walletRPC.js

```
  var request = require('request-promise');

  ...

  _run(method, params) {
    let options = {
      forever: true,
      json: {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': '0', 'method': method}
      auth: {
        'user': 'rpcuser',
        'pass': 'rpcpass',
        'sendImmediately': false
      },
      params: params
    };

    return request.post(`http://127.0.0.1:28083/json_rpc`, options)
    .then((result) => {
      return result;
    });
  }
```

EDIT: also, in my library I have to call a throwaway `get_balance()` ... the first call always fails for me, but subsequent calls work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used digest auth with nodejs but I have used it with PHP to communicate with the rpc wallet. Here's what I did:

First, start `monero-wallet-rpc` with `--rpc-login username:password`.

Then, in your code to connect to the wallet, use:

```
IP=127.0.0.1
PORT=18082
METHOD="make_integrated_address"
PARAMS="{\"payment_id\":\"1234567890123456789012345678900012345678901234567890123456789000\"}"
curl \
-u username:password --digest \
-X POST http://$IP:$PORT/json_rpc \
-d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"'$METHOD'","params":'"$PARAMS"'}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Substitute your username and password as needed, as well as the other fields such as the METHOD.

Comment: That's curl, not PHP though ? The asker says they tried with curl already.

Answer (score 0):

**Try [urllib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urllib) it will work with simple and disgest auth.**

```
const httpClient = require('urllib');
const url = 'https://site.domain.com/xmlapi/xmlapi';
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  // auth: "username:password" use it if you want simple auth
  digestAuth: "username:password",
  content: "Hello world. Data can be json or xml.",
  headers: {
     //'Content-Type': 'application/xml'  use it if payload is xml
     //'Content-Type': 'application/json' use it if payload is json 
    'Content-Type': 'application/text'
  }
};
const responseHandler = (err, data, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  console.log(res.headers);
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
}
httpC
```

lient.request(url, options, responseHandler);